# Get top 2 rows from each distinct field in a column in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `tblHumanResources` in which I want to get the collection of all rows which consists of only 2 rows from each distinct field in the `effectiveDate` column (order by: ascending):

`tblHumanResources` Table

```
| empID | effectiveDate |  Company | Description
| 0-123 |    2014-01-23 | DFD Comp | Analyst
| 0-234 |    2014-01-23 | ABC Comp | Manager
| 0-222 |    2012-02-19 | CDC Comp | Janitor
| 0-213 |    2012-03-13 | CBB Comp | Teller
| 0-223 |    2012-01-23 | CBB Comp | Teller
```

and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try adding LIMIT 2 at the end of your SQL query

Comment: But how do I make it 2 rows per distinct field of effectiveDate column? @ncdreamy

Comment: Can you show us the query and what you've tried so far? Also could you be a bit clearer on what you mean by 2 rows per distinct field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get N rows per group:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (
     SELECT t.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY effectiveDate 
                               ORDER BY empID) 
            as RowNum
     FROM tblHumanResources as t

  ) as t1
WHERE t1.RowNum<=2
ORDER BY effectiveDate
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be9bd/2)</kbd>

Version without ROW_NUMBER() function assuming that `EmpId` is unique during the day:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblHumanResources as t
WHERE t.EmpID IN (SELECT TOP 2
                         EmpID 
                    FROM tblHumanResources as t2
                   WHERE t2.effectiveDate=t.effectiveDate
                   ORDER BY EmpID)
ORDER BY effectiveDate
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/caa65/1)</kbd>

Comment: Noted. But it is giving me an error tho: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: What version of MS SQL Server do you use?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 @valex

Comment: @Sai: v2008 supports this function. [ROW_NUMBER() is supported from 2005 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Well that's weird. The error says "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name." @valex

Comment: @Sai I also added the query without ROW_NUMBER() function into my answer.

Comment: Your code did the trick and I chose this as the answer because this has complete details. Thank you! @valex

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 2
        *
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY effectiveDate ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC ) AS row_num
          FROM      tblHumanResources
        ) AS rows
WHERE   row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

select top 2 *  from tblHumanResources

Comment: This will only return the top 2 rows of my table. I want it to return the collection of rows which consists of 2 rows per distinct field of my column effectiveDate

Answer (score 0):

For each record in the table you select the top 2 rows with the same value in effectiveDate column as the current record in the main select and get the record only if it's empId is in the selected rows in the sub query.

```
select * from tblHumanResources tt
where tt.empID in (select top 2 tt2.empID from tblHumanResources tt2 
                   where tt2.effectiveDate= tt.effectiveDate)
```

Comment: This works but I'm not pretty sure if this fits on what I intend to do. Can you tell me what your code does? My apologies for I am still a bit of a begginer when it comes to SQL.

Comment: I'll try to explain: For each record in the table you select the top 2 rows with the same value in effectiveDate column as the current record in the main select and get the record only if it's empId is in the selected rows in the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TOP 2 *
FROM    (
         SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY effectiveDate ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC) AS row_number
         FROM   tblHumanResources
        ) AS rows
WHERE   row_number = 1
```

Comment: @Sai, Why not give it a go and see for yourself?

Comment: Already tried it before commenting: Says 'row_number' is not a recognized function name. @stmnmn

Comment: Which Version of sql server used ?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 @HiralNayak

Comment: then its work see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: @HiralNayak This is a correct query , Can you just show what you tried and your table structure and output required ?

Comment: but this gives you only 2 records at all, not 2 records for each value in effectiveDate column.

Comment: @Sai SQL 2005 and 2008 do support the ROW_NUMBER OVER() keywords/command. Perhaps are you using SQL 2008 Management Studio to connect to a SQL 2000 machine? Double check with SELECT @@Version that your DB is indeed a SQL 2008 DB.

Comment: @stmnmn is right, this only gives you 2 record, not the collection of 2 rows per distinct value in effectiveDate column.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY effectiveDate ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC) AS RN
FROM tblHumanResources)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Comment: It gives an error that Row_Number is not a function. Note: I am using MS SQL Server 2008 @Nesuke

Comment: Check your version, and also your compatibility version: select @@version

exec sp_dbcmptlevel 'yourDatabaseName' It could be that you have it set to SQL SERVER 2000, which means ROW_NUMBER() will not be recognised.